# How to implement articles in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The Getting Started with Rails guide describes how to implement basic articles in Ruby on Rails.
The body of each article is stored in simple `text` column in the database table.
But I want to have nice articles with images, links, charts, code snippets, and so on.
How can I implement such functionality? Do I have to store HTML in the database table field?

Comment: if you are using rails 6 then try actiontext feature, which by default gives you such features which you are asking for. good luck!

Comment: The question is a bit too broad for StackOverflow. You should look up a tutorial or guide on how to make advanced views in Rails and go from there. If you stumble upon a specific issue along the way, this is the right place to ask. Good luck with Ruby and Rails :)

Answer (score 0):

For images you can use a `attachment` table to attach image to your article. I suggest you use some polymorphic relationships in your table like `attachment`,`code`,...

Answer (score -1):

You will want to store it in plan text. You can create your own preview using something like https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js to create the HTMl in realtime or just the HTML without a preview. However to store into the database and display to the user, you will want to use something like https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet.